# React Native Twitter Login conflict fb and google login iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, twitter-oauth

I know the problem but i have no experience with Objective C and iOS native development

I have two method same name argument different

```
//function 1
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation  {



  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation
          ]
  || [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                         openURL:url
               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                      annotation:annotation
      ];
  }
}


//function 2
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
        return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
      }
```

If i define both like this then both all oauth request after redirect come to function 2. If i try to combine both then twitter not working Twitter only works on function 2 format

```
//combine function 3
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options  {

  NSString *stringurl = url.absoluteString;
  NSString *sub = @"twitterkit";
  NSRange range = [stringurl  rangeOfString: sub options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
  if (range.location != NSNotFound){
    return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
  }
  else{
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation
          ]
  || [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                         openURL:url
               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                      annotation:annotation
      ];
  }
}
```

I cannot add extra argument to function 2 to support google or fb login

How can i handle all request maybe through function overloading but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

I merge them

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    NSString *stringurl = url.absoluteString;
    NSString *sub = @"twitterkit";
    NSRange range = [stringurl  rangeOfString: sub options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound){
    return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
    }
    else{
      BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                      ] || [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                                               openURL:url
                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                            annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                            ];;
      return handled;
    }
  }
```

P.S.
I am using following libraries

react-native-fbsdk

https://differential.com/insights/meteor-google-oauth-from-react-native/
https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                    ] || [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                                             openURL:url
                                   sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                          annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
                          ]
                      || [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url options:options];
    return handled;
}
```

I am using:

[react native twitter signin](https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin) , [react native fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) and [react native google signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin)

Comment: Life Saver <3 <3 <3